# How to hide files by type in Total Commander?

Tags: total-commander

I would like to hide `.DS_Store` files generated by Mac OS, cause I'm switching between Mac/Win very often and I don't like seeing these files in my Dropbox folder when i'm in Windows.

Is it possible to hide them in Total Commander?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly for this purpose, Total Commander maintains a list of ignored files, which can be used to hide many annoyances like this (or Thumbs.db, "System volume information", etc.).

Look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564349/how-to-ignore-svn-folder-when-searching-in-total-commander).